# RxJava group sorted data

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a very large collection of data and the raw data is already sorted by what is going to be the key. For example, I have a CSV file and the first column is going to be the key for the grouping.

```
A,x,x,x
A,x,y,x
A,z,y,y
C,x,s,d
C,t,d,s
B,a,s,a
E,x,x,x
E,t,r,y
```

These lines are converted into objects and put into a list and streamed using RxJava `Flowable`. Because this CSV is going to be huge (so huge that it'll crash the application), is there a good way to convert these objects into a map entry, which would look like this:

```
{ 'A': [[x,x,x],[x,y,x],[z,y,y]] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `FlowableTransformers.partialCollect` now.
An example would be

```
Flowable.fromPublisher(FlowableTransformers.partialCollect(
        (Consumer<PartialCollectEmitter<LineData, Integer, 
        ListBuilder, ListDataModel>>) emitter -> {
            // Get or initialize collecting object
            ListBuilder lb = emitter.getAccumulator();
            if (lb == null) {
                lb = new ListBuilder();
                emitter.setAccumulator(lb);
            }

            if (emitter.demand() != 0) {
                boolean d = emitter.isComplete();
                if (emitter.size() != 0 && !d) {
                    LineData data = emitter.getItem(0);
                    emitter.dropItems(1);

                    // add returns the finished model if the prefix changes
                    ListDataModel model = lb.add(data);

                    if (model != null) {
                        emitter.next(model);
                    }
                } else if (d) {
                    if (!lb.isEmpty()) {
                        // clear returns the last model
                        emitter.next(lb.clear());
                    }
                    emitter.complete();
                    return;
                }
            }
            emitter.setIndex(0);
        }, Functions.emptyConsumer(), settings.getReadBufferSize() + 1).apply(
                Flowable.fromIterable(file.getFileNameList())
                        .concatMap(
                                fileName -> reader
                                        .getLineData(fileName)
                                        .buffer(settings.getReadBufferSize()))
                        .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collectWhile` from [rxjava2-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras) and specify the collection factory to produce a special keyed object:

```java
class Keyed {
    final K key;
    final List<Value> list;
    ...
}

K key(Value value) {
 ...
}

source.compose(
  Transformers.
    collectWhile(
      // factory
      () -> new Keyed(),
      // add
      (keyed, x) -> { 
          keyed.list.add(x);
          return keyed; },
      // condition
      (keyed, x) -> 
         keyed.list.isEmpty() ||
         key(x).equals(keyed.key)));
```